# Aura attribute of type List not accepting an array of objects

Tags: javascript, list, aura, object

I would like to pass an array of objects from my js file to an aura attribute. I know the list contains values and is correct before I pass it to the aura component but the list is empty when I log that attribute to the console.

Helper method:

```
//convert map into list of objects for Aura
                var objects = [];
                for(var rawLineItem in result.rawLineItemToContactIdList) {
                    objects.push({key:rawLineItem, value:result.rawLineItemToContactIdList[rawLineItem]});
                    console.log('objects: ' + JSON.stringify(objects));
                }
                component.set("v.objectList", objects);
```

Aura attribute:

```
<aura:attribute name="objectList" type="List" />
```

**EDIT: Then I log the objectList varible to the console:**

Aura:

```
<button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" onclick="{!c.showDupes}" >Log</button>
```

Helper:

```
showDupes: function(component, event, helper) {
        var objectList = component.get("v.objectList");

        console.log('objectList: ' + JSON.stringify(objectList));
    },
```

Comment: I am not sure why this fails. Try setting it to `Object[]` and see if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks @SebastianKessel, I already tried that but still no luck. It's weird because when i console.log the objects it is showing, but then when I log the objectList attribute it's empty

Comment: Something else must be at play there. Is there any other code futzing with that attribute? Are you in an architecture with inheritance? More details would be appreciated.

Comment: How does the problem manifest itself? Can you clarify the "not accepting" part?

Comment: I set `objectList` at the bottom of my Helper code after logging it to the console, knowing it's correct. Then I have a button which calls a function in the helper to console.log that attribute. I will add the code for that function

Comment: you also might want to consider sharing an example of your map structure before conversion, and a sample list after conversion.

Answer (score 1):

It was a dumb error where I passed in the aura component as 'cmp' instead of component. when i switched it form `component.set("v.objectList", objects);`
 to `cmp.set("v.objectList", objects); it worked. Thanks for the help!`

Comment: ha, nice catch, thanks for posting your solution =)